# Is it possible to take two files open in VS Code and open them in Beyond Compare?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, sublimetext3, beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

I have recently switched from Sublime Text to VS Code (WIN10). I prefer VS Code now, as it' so much better, but I have something I can't figure out, and it seems crazy that there isn't a solution.

The VS Code Diff display is no good for actually editing, so I use Beyond Compare for all my diff-ing and merging.

I've searched high and low and can't find anything like a replacement for the ST3 plugin "FileDiffs"  (https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FileDiffs).

I already have Beyond Compare set as my diff tool in .gitconfig, and I have the VS Code extensions for diff-ing with remote tools "when using Git" -- but what about when you just have two arbitrary files open in VS code, and I just want to open them in Beyond Compare?? This appears to be impossible in VS Code without using some very inefficient workaround.

(maybe I need to learn how to port a ST3 extension to VS Code...)

Answer (score 3):

Check out PartialDiff: https://github.com/ryu1kn/vscode-partial-diff

Quoted from its docs,

> You can compare (diff) text selections within a file, across different files, or to the clipboard.
>
> Compare text in 2 visible editors (i.e. tabs) with one action.

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for your suggestion. I've tried that extension out, but unfortunately it doesn't appear to support using an external diff tool such as Beyond Compare. Instead it just opens the VS Code Diff comparison window.